# Oracle SQL group by week /month

Tags: oracle

How can we group reocrds weekly/monthly in oracle between from date and to date so that one record can be returned for one week/month.

e.g If we have 5 records for Ist weeek and 3 records for second week between a from date and to date then it should return total 2 records(one for Ist week and one for second week).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please improve your example with some test data.

Answer (score 3):

You can group the results using  `GROUP BY`: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php

To select only those between from date and to date use `WHERE`

**EDIT**

For selecting the begining of the week or month, you can use `TRUNC`(the_date_field, ): http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php

For example this groups by week:

```
SELECT TRUNC(datecol_name, 'WW') FROM table_name GROUP BY TRUNC(datecol_name, 'WW');
```

Comment: this is half of the answer I would say. You need to group by, indeed but you would like to know how to group by using the date spans. This I how I would do it: GROUP BY trunc(the_date_field, <the_format>) and format you can get from there: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php you will get beginning of the week/month for given row and this will group and sum up the data according to that field

Comment: thanks, I'll edit it in. I wasn't quite sure what the question was refering to.